# Visual Studio Unit Tests: Run from Excel

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2015, vba

I asked a question here a while back, about solutions for making a GUI for running units tests from Visual Studio. No answers, so it doesn't seem to be something many people see the need for. However, I do.

So I got to thinkin: Is it possible to use the VS Developer Command Prompt? That is, have an Excel macro that starts the command prompt, runs the specified test(s) and gets the results?

The shortcut for opening the Developer Command Prmpt for VS2015 is

```
%comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat""
```

and a test can be run from there like this:

```
MSTest.exe /testcontainer:TestProject.dll /test:MainFolder.Subfolder.TestClass.TestMethod
```

However, I'm not too familiar with VBA, so I haven't been able to figure out how to create a macro for running this from Excel. If at all possible.

What I'd like to is be able to run the tests from Excel via a button and macro, and get the results from MSTest into the same file.

Comment: I'm really surprised that no one has an answer for this? It's a question of running a specific shell, send it commands and receive the output. If this was Unix/Linux, I could probably help. But if it's not a straight-forward thing in Windows that's a pretty serious thing imo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, enable the Developer mode in Excel.

Then, create a button and assign it to a macro. If you don't know how, there are lots of basic tutorials for this on the net.

In the VBA editor, insert the following code in the macro you've created and assigned to the button (the name of the Sub is the macro):

```
Sub Knapp1_Klikk()
    Dim testPath As String
    testPath = "..\Source\Workspaces\QA\Opus3Automation\Tests\bin\Debug"
    Set Wsh = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    Wsh.Run ("%comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"" & d: & MSTest.exe /testcontainer:d:\path-to-application-source\Tests\bin\Debug\Tests.dll /test:Testprojectname.Testfoldername.Testsubfoldername.Testclassname.Testname")
End Sub
```

(Of course, the test name will run the specific test method, while skipping it will run the whole test class (all test methods).

Comment: Perfect! Thanks :-)